# How to get random point near edges of a square in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, point

I want to make a function that gives me a random point near the edges of a rectangle from a point. This is what I came up with so far, but I have absolutely no idea why it is not working.

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomPointNearEdges(rectPos, width, height, border) {
  var point = new Point(rectPos.x, rectPos.y);
  if (randomNumber(0, 1) == 0) {
    point.x = randomNumber(rectPos.x, rectPos.x + border);
    if (randomNumber(0, 1) == 0) {
      point.y = randomNumber(rectPos.y, rectPos.y + border);
    }
    else {
      point.y = randomNumber(rectPos.y + height, (rectPos.y + height) + border);
    }
  }
  else {
    point.y = randomNumber(rectPos.y, rectPos.y + border);
    if (randomNumber(0, 1) == 0) {
      point.y = randomNumber(rectPos.x, rectPos.x + border);
    }
    else {
      point.y = randomNumber(rectPos.x + height, (rectPos.x + width) + border);
    }
  }
  return point;
};

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = 700;
  canvas.height = 700;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeRect(130, 130, 500, 500);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var point = getRandomPointNearEdges(new Point(130, 130), 500, 500, 100);
    ctx.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 2, 2);
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Just to clarify, the black region in this 'Not to scale' diagram is where I want to allow the point to generate. The width / height of that black region is the border property in the code snippet.

[image: Diagram]

Why is my function not working?

Comment: For the second question, `fillRect` takes width and height, so your 3rd and 4th params should be `1, 1`.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, idk why I did that for strokeRect and not fillRect. But the function still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Random with even distribution.

Just to point out that the answer by [SimpleJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581326/3877726)  is statistical flawed with the distribution of random locations having a bias to the corners and then to the shorter sides, even though they cover much less area.

The ideal random location should be spread equally over the area in question, if the height of the box is less than the width then there is less chance of the the sides getting a point.

The example below provides a much faster and a much better distribution. I have added the given answers solution as well so you can compare.

The function that gets a random pos. The arguments `x`,`y` top left inside edge of rectangle, `w`,`h` inside width and height of the rectangle `minDist`, `maxDist` the min and max dist the random point can be from the inside edge of the box. You can also use negative values have the points outside the rectangle. Note that the distances are always from the inside edge of the box. The values are also floored when return (can easily be remove and still works)

```
function randomPointNearRect(x, y, w, h, minDist, maxDist) {
  const dist = (Math.random() * (maxDist - minDist) + minDist) | 0;
  x += dist;
  y += dist;
  w -= dist  * 2
  h -= dist  * 2
  if (Math.random() <  w / (w + h)) { // top bottom
    x = Math.random() * w + x;
    y = Math.random() < 0.5 ? y : y + h -1;
  } else {
    y = Math.random() * h + y;
    x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? x: x + w -1;
  }
  return [x | 0, y | 0];
}
```

Note there is a slight bias to the inside of the box. It can be removed with a little calculus with the bias rate of change `f'(x) = 8*x` 8 pixels per pixel inward and the anti derivative `f(x)=4*(x**2) + c` would directly relate to the distribution. Where x is dist from edge and c is related to perimeter length

### Example to compare

The example has two canvases. Many random points are drawn. click the top canvas to add more points. Note how the bottom canvas sides and corners get darker due to the bias of the random points.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.onclick = ()=>{
  getRandomPointsForBox(200, box,4, 18);
  getRandomPoints(200);
}
const edgeClear = 30;
var box = {
  x: edgeClear,
  y: edgeClear,
  w: canvas.width - edgeClear * 2,
  h: canvas.height - edgeClear * 2,
  edge: 4,
}

function drawBox(box) {
  ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h);
  ctx.clearRect(box.x + box.edge, box.y + box.edge, box.w - box.edge * 2, box.h - box.edge * 2);
}

function drawPixel(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function getRandomPointsForBox(count, box, min, max) {
  min += box.edge;
  max += box.edge;
  while (count--) {
    const [x, y] = randomPointNearRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h, min, max);
    drawPixel(x, y);
  }
  
}

drawBox(box);
getRandomPointsForBox(200, box,4, 18);
ctx.font = "18px arial"
ctx.textAlign = "center"
ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
ctx.fillText("Click to add more random points.",canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);



function randomPointNearRect(x, y, w, h, minDist, maxDist) {
  const dist = (Math.random() * (maxDist - minDist) + minDist) | 0;
  x += dist;
  y += dist;
  w -= dist  * 2
  h -= dist  * 2
  if (Math.random() <  w / (w + h)) { // top bottom
    x = Math.random() * w + x;
    y = Math.random() < 0.5 ? y : y + h -1;
  } else {
    y = Math.random() * h + y;
    x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? x: x + w -1;
  }
  return [x | 0, y | 0];
}









/* The following is from the answer provided by SimpleJ https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581326/3877726 */

const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

const rect = {
  x: box.x, y: box.y,
  width: box.w, height: box.h,
};

drawRect(rect);

ctx1.font = "18px arial"
ctx1.textAlign = "center"
ctx1.textBaseline = "middle"
ctx1.fillText("SimpleJ's method.",canvas1.width / 2, canvas1.height / 2);
ctx1.fillText("Note density of sides and corners.",canvas1.width / 2, canvas1.height / 2 + 20);

function getRandomPoints(count) {
  while (count--) {
    drawPoint(randomPointInRect(sample(rects)));
  }
}


var rects = getBorderRects(rect, 10);




function getBorderRects(rect, distance) {
  const { x, y, width, height } = rect;
  return [
    {x: x, y: y, width: width, height: distance}, // top
    {x: x, y: y + height - distance, width: width, height: distance}, // bottom
    {x: x, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // left
    {x: x + width - distance, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // right
  ];
}

function sample(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function randomPointInRect({x, y, width, height}) {
  return {
    x: x + (Math.random() * width),
    y: y + (Math.random() * height),
  };
}
function drawRect({x, y, width, height}) {
  ctx1.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
}
function drawPoint({x, y}) {
  ctx1.fillRect(x, y, 1,1);
}
  getRandomPoints(200);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, marked as right answer for the clean and flawless code.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about the problem of getting a random point near an edge as getting a random point in one of four edge rectangles, this problem becomes much easier to break down:

1. Get edge rectangles.
2. Pick a random edge rectangle.
3. Generate a random point in the edge rectangle.

To generate edge rectangles, we need a max distance (how far from the edge can the point be?):

```
function getBorderRects(rect, distance) {
  const { x, y, width, height } = rect;
  return [
    {x: x, y: y, width: width, height: distance}, // top
    {x: x, y: y + height - distance, width: width, height: distance}, // bottom
    {x: x, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // left
    {x: x + width - distance, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // right
  ];
}
```

To pick a random rectangle from our array of edge rectangles, we can define a `sample` function:

```
function sample(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

Then to pick a random point in a rectangle, we just need some `Math.random`:

```
function randomPointInRect({x, y, width, height}) {
  return {
    x: x + (Math.random() * width),
    y: y + (Math.random() * height),
  };
}
```

And putting everything together:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const rect = {
  x: 10, y: 20,
  width: 300, height: 200,
};

drawRect(rect);

drawPoint(
  randomPointInRect(
    sample(
      getBorderRects(rect, 10)
    )
  )
);


function getBorderRects(rect, distance) {
  const { x, y, width, height } = rect;
  return [
    {x: x, y: y, width: width, height: distance}, // top
    {x: x, y: y + height - distance, width: width, height: distance}, // bottom
    {x: x, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // left
    {x: x + width - distance, y: y, width: distance, height: height}, // right
  ];
}

function sample(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function randomPointInRect({x, y, width, height}) {
  return {
    x: x + (Math.random() * width),
    y: y + (Math.random() * height),
  };
}

function drawRect({x, y, width, height}) {
  context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
}

function drawPoint({x, y}) {
  context.arc(x, y, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, so my logic was wrong entirely, I was trying to randomly choose a side for the random number. Thanks again!

Comment: I like that this answer is significantly more flexible as you can add whatever boxes you'd like in `getBorderRects()`

Answer (score 1):

For anybody here like me, looking for a short, simple solution, this post is closest I found that is not talking trigonometry .. An while what I came up with might not directly be a solution to OPs problem, maybe someone will find this useful..

The approach is fairly simple.

`Math.random()` a number between 0 & 800. Make use of modulus and divide what's left by 200 to get a random side and axis point. Push the random side all the way, assign the random value to the other axis and yeah, that's about it .. here's an ex:

```
let rndm = Math.floor(Math.random()*800-1);
let offset = rndm % 200;
let side = (rndm - offset) / 200; // 0:top 1:right 2:btm 3:left
let y = side % 2 > 0 ? offset+1 : 100 * side ;
let x = side % 2 < 1 ? offset+1 : 100 * (side - 1) ;

point.y = y - 100;
point.x = x - 100;
```

In my case, I needed both negative and positive values with an origin point.
And if you want to spawn a point inside a border, just do another random number spanning the width of the border.

Just remember to adjust the corners.

```
offset += rndmBorder * 2;         // creates an inward line in the corners
point.x = x - 100 + rndmBorder;   // still keeping the origin point nice and center
                                _____________
                                |\_________/|  <-// inward line
                                | |       | |
                                | |       | |
```

All I was in need for is to offset some letters .. and most of what I found seemed like overkill .. This actually works fairly well, hope it helps.